# Varnish - how to parse StatSess lines from varnishlog

Tags: varnish

I'm trying to analyze the output of varnishlog, but I'm having trouble finding a good reference on what data is presented by the individual tags - in particular, I'm insteresed in the StatSess tag, as I suspect it holds most of the information I'm interested in (i.e. did the session result in a cache hit? how many bytes were served? etc).  My overall goal is to determine per host cache usage (I have multiple host names/domains behind varnish instance)

Can some one point me in the direction of a useful glossary of these tags, or give me any tips on how I might get the result I'm trying to achieve?

Thanks in advance.